# Stop the progress bar from spinning and diisplaying the results entered?

Tags: java, android, progress-bar

I am creating an app that will get numbers between 0-100 from the user, then getting the average and displaying it in a progress bar. For example the user enters 100, 80 and 75 the total is 255 and the average is 85 so i would like the progress bar to fill 3/4 of the circle and stop. At the moment the progress bar keeps spinning in circles and doesn't stop at the location I want even when I specify it with  `.setProgress(85)`. Could anybody help me out I'm quite stuck here's my code:

xml:

```
    <ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/mProgressBar"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:rotation="-90"/>
```

java:

```
    mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.mProgressBar);
    mProgressBar = new ProgressBar(ActivityA.this, null,    android.R.attr.progressBarStyleLarge);
    mProgressBar.setProgress(30);
    mProgressBar.setMax(100);
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it with a simple progress bar.

Please take a look to this [github](https://github.com/Todd-Davies/ProgressWheel) or you might want to use a progress Dialog instead. Here is [a good tutorial](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/ui/progressdialog/android-progressdialog-example/), easy to follow.

Ex :

```
    barProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    barProgressDialog.setTitle("Downloading Image ...");
    barProgressDialog.setMessage("Download in progress ...");
    barProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(barProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
    barProgressDialog.setProgress(0);
    barProgressDialog.setMax(20);
    barProgressDialog.show();
```

This is pretty much what you want to do.

Hope it helps !